# Private types, units of measure when is it a good idea?

Tags: functional-programming, f#

My question is regarding using private type in F#.

Consider the case we have some application and we have some library. One may consider using units within the library, and making them private behind this "layer". App needs to use a specific unit to use library functions.

```
[<Measure>]
type private year

[<Measure>]
type private second

let inline asSeconds time : float<second> = float time * 1.0<second>
let asYear time = 1.0<year> * float time
let secondsToYears secs = secs * 1.0<year/second> * 3.1688739e-8

[<Test>]
let FloatFunctionCanDeconstructsUnit() =
    let ans = float(asSeconds 123)
    Assert.AreEqual(123., ans)
```

Has anyone implemented something like this? What are your thoughts? Does it seem like overkill?
Some have suggested in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2666311/pattern-matching-of-units-of-measure-in-f) (11 years old) that one should just use objects for this. e.g.

```
type SomeValue = 
  | M of float<m>
  | MPS of float<m/s>
```

P.S. Excuse my casual use of terminology.

Comment: Time and how to represent and compute it would deserve a StackExchange community by itself.

Answer (score 1):

A date is a point in time (year, month etc. or seconds from a starting point). It is changed from and to text for display purposes.

A duration is measured in seconds. You can change it to and from text, but having different units is only confusing. Especially since “day”, “week”, “month” and “year” don’t have a fixed length and are only used to modify dates *together with a calendar*.

PS “float” is totally inadequate in this case. Nowhere near enough precision.

PS. When my computer takes the current date and adds a month, and your computer takes the current date and adds a month, at the exact same moment, the correct results can be three days apart. Can you figure out when that would happen?